# knitr fig.cap with markdown syntax to latex

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc, bookdown

When I convert following R markdown

````
```{r UCSC, fig.cap="**My** [UCSC](http://www.text.com)"}
knitr::include_graphics("ucsc.png")
```
````

to latex, it will generate

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{"ucsc.png"}
\caption{**My** [UCSC](http://www.text.com)}
\end{figure}
```

The markdown syntax was **not** transformed to latex code `\href{http://www.text.com}{UCSC}`.

How can I configure to transfer markdown syntax in `fig.cap` to correct latex code?

A solution was found in [`bookdown`](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/markdown-extensions-by-bookdown.html) (Text References) document.

````
A normal paragraph.

(ref:foo) A scatterplot of the data `cars` using **base** R graphics. 

```{r foo, fig.cap='(ref:foo)'}
plot(cars)  # a scatterplot
```
````

Thanks!

Tong

Comment: Sorry for the bothering. The solution was introduced in `bookdown` document.

Comment: You are welcome to answer your own question below (instead of inserting it in the question).

Comment: @YihuiXie, is this working yet? I couldn't reproduce this. The caption output stays as "(ref:foo)".

Comment: @CainãMaxCouto-Silva Are you using bookdown?

Comment: @YihuiXie, no, I'm not! I just knit a .Rmd file (pdf as output).

Comment: This post is about bookdown, and the feature is only available in bookdown (and R Markdown extensions built on top of it).